# Image viewer jittery image when hiding and reappearing system ui overlay

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a simple image viewer, on Android it's like viewing a media on WhatsApp or even the Gallery. On click these apps will hide the top and bottom system overlay UI or go into Fullscreen mode while viewing the image. I tried to recreate this in Flutter. The best solution so far that I got was stacking another container behind the bottom system navigation UI with a fixed and similar height but the issue remains, I can see a pixel of movement on the image. In these apps, it's as if the overlay is perfectly stacked on top of the image/widget as the image is staying perfectly still.

Expected result: The image is positioned behind of system UI overlay without any movement/resizing

Actual result: The image is very jittery in between transitions

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class ViewImagesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ViewImagesScreen({super.key, required this.url});

  final String url;

  @override
  State<ViewImagesScreen> createState() => _ViewImagesScreenState();
}

class _ViewImagesScreenState extends State<ViewImagesScreen> {
  bool isAppBarVisible = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setSystemOverlay(true);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            isAppBarVisible = !isAppBarVisible;
            setSystemOverlay(isAppBarVisible);
          });
        },
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned.fill(
              bottom: 0,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned.fill(
              top: isAppBarVisible ? kToolbarHeight : 0,
              child: InteractiveViewer(
                child: Image.network(
                  widget.url,
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            if (isAppBarVisible)
              Positioned(
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                child: AppBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(100),
                  leading: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_back,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void setSystemOverlay(bool isVisible) {
    if (isVisible) {
      SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
        SystemUiMode.manual,
        overlays: [
          SystemUiOverlay.top,
          SystemUiOverlay.bottom,
        ],
      );
    } else {
      SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
        SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    setSystemOverlay(true);
  }
}
```